# Did the Close and 'Do Not Close' Buttons in the Close Review Queue get swapped round?

Tags: discussion, review, vote-to-close

My muscle memory is shot to pieces.  I've had to chase down <del>three</del> five duplicates that nearly got away...

[image]

Is this my imagination?  Is the new button order better?

Comment: I thought that was just me! I've clicked "Do Not Close" a couple times, accidentally!

Comment: Phew... It's not just me - thanks Andrew.

Comment: for best usability, review queue buttons would better change their order at every new item. It wouldn't also hurt to change their location. And the looks. And, maybe (just maybe!:) the meaning as well. This would help in [fighting mindless clicking and fake reviews from badge hunters](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/149621/165773)

Comment: @gnat "Usability" you keep using that word...I do not think it means what you think it means

Comment: @BenBrocka buttons order, location and the looks are usability matters aren't they?

Comment: @gnat yes, but intentionally making them hard to use is the opposite of making them usable. There may be intentional design decisions which drive such poor usability issues with a net benefit (for community over the user) but it, in and of itself, is still harmful to usability.

Comment: @BenBrocka agreed. Word "best" in [my prior comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151762/did-the-close-and-do-not-close-buttons-in-the-close-review-queue-get-swapped-r#comment435702_151762) doesn't apply to usability, that's for sure :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For what it's worth, the rationale here was that the first option in the Low Quality queue is "Looks Good", so putting the big red button first in this queue was... Perhaps a bit too encouraging.

Note that we're still a bit inconsistent though - the edit button jumps around queue-to-queue as well, so it's possible we'll do a bit more reshuffling if Geoff feels sleepy.

Hey, the URL still has "beta" in it...

Answer (score 11):

Yes, they did get swapped - enjoy the new surprise and stay alert.  We need everyone to stay alert while on review.

Comment: Slap your face a couple of times.  Go get another cup of coffee.

Comment: But Geoff you're torturing us!  Won't some 'less diligent' people just let the accidental 'Do Not Closes' go? (It is amusing though...)

Comment: Good, expecting to see the Edit button sit in the bolt button places soon

Comment: We're here at Stack Overflow's prestigious /review queue, where we've secretly replaced the Close button with Folger's Crystals. Let's see if anyone notices!

Comment: could we just have them randomly swapped, and occationally get replaced with a button that makes a vuvuzela noise? That would cut down on bad reviews ;p